# How to play mp4 videos in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I'm trying to play a video using a file path in React, I've tried using ReactPlayer and just the video element and can't get it to work.

the video is in the same folder at App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ReactPlayer url="jadenSmith.mp4" type="video/mp4" playing />
        <video src="./jadenSmith.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls></video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are there any console errors ?

Comment: Put your video in public folder, then add it to src="/jadenSmith.mp4"